# evil mode - make helm quit with the escape key

Tags: helm, evil

I followed [this guide](http://juanjoalvarez.net/es/detail/2014/sep/19/vim-emacsevil-chaotic-migration-guide/) to make escape quit from various modes...

```
;; esc quits
(defun minibuffer-keyboard-quit ()
  "Abort recursive edit.
In Delete Selection mode, if the mark is active, just deactivate it;
then it takes a second \\[keyboard-quit] to abort the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (and delete-selection-mode transient-mark-mode mark-active)
      (setq deactivate-mark  t)
    (when (get-buffer "*Completions*") (delete-windows-on "*Completions*"))
    (abort-recursive-edit)))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map [escape] 'keyboard-quit)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map [escape] 'keyboard-quit)
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [escape] 'minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
(define-key minibuffer-local-ns-map [escape] 'minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map [escape] 'minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
(define-key minibuffer-local-must-match-map [escape] 'minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
(define-key minibuffer-local-isearch-map [escape] 'minibuffer-keyboard-quit)
(global-set-key [escape] 'evil-exit-emacs-state)
```

To make helm quit using escape, I tried:

`(define-key helm-map [escape] 'helm-keyboard-quit)`

This didn't work. Setting other keys instead of escape works fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function `my-helm-init` which runs `(define-key helm-map (kbd "ESC") 'helm-keyboard-quit)`

Call `my-helm-init` from the `after-init-hook`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - looking at those links made me find the solution that worked for me. The solution was to set the keymapping in the after-init-hook

Comment: Edited the answer for the solution

Comment: This only works for emacs GUI i.e. emacs running in its own window. When running emacs -nw in Linux gnome-terminal / xterm, I need ESC thrice.

Comment: Could you provide a full example? I can't figure out what the after-init-hook part should look like

Comment: It quits but still shows up on the buffer section